# select a max for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi given the original table below, how do you write a query to get max price and its date just like the result below. This is in sql server.

Original table: tblstock

```
symbol, date, price
aapl, 2/2/2015, 115
aapl, 2/3/2015, 119.56
aapl, 2/4/2015, 116
aapl, 2/5/2015, 109
aapl, 2/6/2015, 107.56
```

wanted result:

```
symbol, date, price, highpricedate, highprice
aapl, 2/2/2015, 115, 2/3/2015, 119.56
aapl, 2/3/2015, 119.56, 2/3/2015, 119.56
aapl, 2/4/2015, 116, 2/3/2015, 119.56
aapl, 2/5/2015, 109, 2/3/2015, 119.56
aapl, 2/6/2015, 107.56, 2/3/2015, 119.56
```

Comment: What is the point to duplicate data? Why not select it separately as 1 row 2 column result set?

Comment: For reporting purpose, so it will run faster

Comment: "it will run faster" --- who told you that? "2 queries is faster than 1" --- is not always true. And I would say that if one asks/states that - the chance it's the opposite. And it always surprises me when someone says "it will be faster" when they cannot even realize how the query looks like.

Comment: What version of SQLServer are you using?

Comment: @zerkms, in this case it really depends on the software used to display the results. If the business is asking for results in exactly this format, then stitching two queries together could present a problem for the front end.

Comment: @JNevill in this case the OP has confirmed they want to do that because of "so it will run faster" not because a reporting software requires that. At least if it was the format requirement I would never mention speed (but that's me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend `outer apply` for this:

```
select t.*, tmax.date as highpricedate, tmax.price as highprice
from tblstock t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from tblstock t2
      where t2.symbol = t.symbol
      order by t2.price desc
     ) tmax;
```

Actually, `cross apply` would work just as well.

Comment: The caveat here is that if you have more than one stock symbol, the `highpricedate` and `highprice` will be for ALL stock prices in the table.

Comment: You do have a small typo in the `where` clause. It needs to correlate with the outer query.

Comment: You also have a another small typo in the select clause. t2 doesn't exists anymore there. Refer to tmax instead..

Answer (score 2):

You can use windows function.
Explanation :
With Windows function (or over clause if you prefer) you can easily get the HighPrice.

Getting HighPriceDate was a bit more tricky, but still fairly simple.
By ranking each row for partitions with Row_Number, we can than use the Lag function to get the HighPriceDate.

```
SELECT  symbol,
        [date],
        price,
        highprice       = MAX(price) OVER(PARTITION BY symbol),
        HighPriceDate   = LAG([date], i - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY i)
FROM (  SELECT  *,
                i = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY PRICE DESC)
        FROM @tblstock) AS Sub
```

Comment: High price date is missing..., so forget this answer until I fix it.

Comment: Fixed, Used Row_Number with Lag fonction to retreive the High price date.  Should work well.

Comment: Nice solution. I personally love windows functions. Just so you know, only ROW_NUMBER() was introduced in SQL Server 2008. LAG(),LEAD() and the others weren't introduced until 2012. That way when someone needs a 2008 solution, you know which functions you can use!